# После разлогирования необходимо обновить страницу, чтобы произошел редирект. 1с Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Проблема следующая - при нажатии на кнопку выход происходит редирект на главную страницу личного кабинета, но выход из личного кабинета не осуществляется, но если обновить страницу пользователя перебрасывает на страницу с авторизацией.

Кнопка "выход" находится по адресу

```
mobile-myclub/pages/profilePage/profilePage.php
```

Код который отвечает за разлогирование пользователя

```
        <a href="../../auth/?logout=yes" class="defaultButton-gray d-fl">
            <div class="defaultButton-gray--img">
                <img src="<?= SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/images/icon/exit.svg" alt="card user">
            </div>
            <span>Выйти из аккаунта</span>
        </a>
```

На главной странице есть условие которое проверяет параметры GET

```
    if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == "Y") {
       $USER->Logout();
       LocalRedirect("./auth/");
    }

    if (!$USER->IsAuthorized()) LocalRedirect("./auth/"); // Если не авторизирован делаем редирект
```

Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выход пользователя сразу перебрасывало на страницу с авторизацией

Страница с авторизацией находится по адресу

```
mobile-myclub/auth/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно так

```
if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == "yes") {
  $USER->Logout();
  LocalRedirect("./auth/");
}
```

т.к. в `GET` параметр у вас `logout=yes`

Comment: "facepalm"... Спасибо большое! Совсем не заметил ...

Comment: всё равно необходима перезагрузка страницы. Проверил, что показывает в панели разработчика в "сети" - статус 302 + URL - mobile-myclub/auth/?logout=yes

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, проверка на параметр logout делается в ядре и дополнительная проверка где-либо не требуется. Поэтому достаточно просто в адресе указать нужный адрес и параметр. И желательно указать адрес абсолютный - от корня сайта, а не относительный. Тогда кнопка будет работать на всех страницах.

```
 <a href="/auth/?logout=yes" class="defaultButton-gray d-fl">
     <div class="defaultButton-gray--img">
          <img src="<?= SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/images/icon/exit.svg" alt="card user">
     </div>
     <span>Выйти из аккаунта</span>
 </a>
```

Comment: Но почему-то необходимо принудительно обновить страницу и только в этом случае происходит разлогирование

Comment: Значит, какие-то проблемы с переадресацией. Почему у вас адрес перехода "../../auth/", а проверка делается на главной странице? Какое отношение главная страница имеет к "../../auth/"?

Comment: 1. я делаю проверку на каждой странице к которой пользователь не должен иметь доступ без авторизации. 2. На главную страницу перебрасывает пользователя после нажатия на кнопку выход. 3. Я заметил, что если просматривать сайт через инкогнито, то таких проблем нет вообще. Может ли быть проблема в кэшировании?

Comment: Я пробовал убирать проверки и оставил только кнопку выхода с параметрами /auth/?logout=yes. При таком подходе вообще не происходит разлогирования.

Comment: когда осуществляется первый вход в приложение (очищены куки и кэш), вход и выход происходит корректно, но после первого входа и выхода, необходимо каждый раз обновлять страницу для того чтобы осуществить вход и разлогирование.

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего, проблема в кэшировании.